# PyCharm does not resolve templates nor template tags nor statics in Django project

Tags: django, pycharm

PyCharm does not find templates, nor template tags, nor static files in my Django project even though the project itself is set up right and working.

I am using Django `1.6.2` with this layout:

```
proj
  .devtmp
  manage.py
  proj
    settings.py
    app1
      templatetags
  app2
    templates
    static
```

and with settings like these:

```
from os.path import join, dirname, pardir, abspath

PROJECT_ROOT = abspath(join(dirname(__file__), pardir))
DEV_TMP_DIR = join(PROJECT_ROOT, pardir, '.devtmp')

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'templates'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = join(DEV_TMP_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = join(DEV_TMP_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    ...
    'proj'
    'proj.app1'
    'app2'
)
```

**Update:**

In the IDE preferences, I have configured paths to the project root, **`settings.py`** and **`manage.py`**. In addition, I have configured the project interpreter (I am running the runserver from the IDE right now with no problems).

Answer (score 27):

Please try this - it works for me for templates:

- set templates directories in *Python Template Languages -> Template directories*
- in *Project Structure* mark your apps as *Source Folders*

**EDIT :**
After a project structure reorganization I had problem with static files again. Setting destination of `setting.py` file in *Django Support* -> *Settings* resolved the issue.

Comment: Setting Template directories did work, thank you! Marking apps as source folders did nothing, though (statics and template tags still not resolved). This really sucks about PyCharm, I don't understand why this sometimes works and sometimes not, when Django has no problem at all.

Comment: why does pycharm insist on this marking of template folders now to resolve paths? SO annoying and bizarre.

Comment: Brilliant @glowka suggestion in your edit worked like a charm... PyCharm to be specific...

Answer (score 14):

Right click on the templates directory and  "Mark Directory As" -> "Template Directory" and select template language as django

Answer (score 13):

I've solved this problem by editing settings for Django framework, as seen on a picture.
[image: PICTURE]

Comment: Fixed my problem, I had renamed the project previously

Comment: Fixed my problem, I had moved stuff around.

Answer (score 11):

You need to set up your project properly.

**Django Set Up**

In `Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | Django`, Enable Django Suport, set up the path to your project's root, `settings.py` file, and `manage.py` file:

[image]

**Mark your templates directory as Templates**

In `File | Settings | Project Structure` for Windows/Linux and
`PyCharm | Preferences | Project Structure` for macOS, choose the directory to be marked as a template root.

[image]

Click on `Templates` on `Mark as`.

[image]

4. Click on OK to apply the changes you made.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that I was doing this in my settings module:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [*INSTALLED_APPS, "debug_toolbar"]
```

This caused PyCharm to think that `debug_toolbar` is the only app in the entire project. Declaring `INSTALLED_APPS` in the standard way solved it.